# Get data statistics in R with rmongodb or RMongo

Tags: r, mongodb, mongodb-query, rmongodb, rmongo

Using robomongo I can get basic description of the data using

```
db.getCollection('Exempt').stats()
```

but i cannot seem to get this info in nR using the rmongodb or RMongo packages.

Can anyone please help?

Regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this information (and more) using `library(mongolite)`. The command you want is `mongo$info()`

```
library(mongolite)

mongo <- mongo(collection = "test", db = "test")
info <- mongo$info()
info$stats

# $ns
# [1] "test.test"
# 
# $count
# [1] 0
# 
# $size
# [1] 0
# 
# $storageSize
# [1] 8192
# 
# $numExtents
# [1] 1
# 
# $nindexes
# [1] 1
# 
# $lastExtentSize
# [1] 8192
# 
# $paddingFactor
# [1] 1
# 
# $systemFlags
# [1] 1
# 
# $userFlags
# [1] 1
# 
# $totalIndexSize
# [1] 8176
# 
# $indexSizes
# $indexSizes$`_id_`
# [1] 8176
# 
# 
# $ok
# [1] 1

rm(mongo); gc()
```